# A 110 kb .NET 4.0 app needs 10 seconds for a cold start, thats not acceptable !

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, startup

I am using the .NET 4.0 client profile for my app and I run a dual core with 4 GB Ram and a fast hard disk.

nothing big is done at the start just showing a generic List in a wpf listview.

How can I make the cold start faster of my assembly ?

I have done now again a cold start and run the windowsapplication.exe in my \obj\x86\Debug folder and my harddisk run like hell and it took 10,5 seconds ???

What is wrong?

The warm start after the cold one took  1 second.

Java 6 apps has not that problem, not at all just to compare...

**UPDATE:**

I remove all methods which read data when my ViewModels are created.

Still 10 seconds to show up. Its not a problem of reading data from RAM. The problem is the heavily busy harddisk which has never been that loud except running a .net 4.0 wpf app...

I do not reference any 3rd party dll`s.

These are the assemblies I reference:

Microsoft.CSharp
Presentation.Core
PresentationFramework
System
System.Core
System.Data
System.Xaml
System.Xml
System.Xml.Ling
WindowsBase

**UPDATE 2:**

I created now a .NET 4.0 wpf project from scratch with just a empty window and green background;-)

The cold start took 3 seconds (Hard disk got very busy)

then I run my other wpf app which took earlier 10 seconds. Now it needs only 1,5 seconds to show up on screen.

The situation is now clear to me:

My application as nothing what could make it slow. Its just about the FIRST wpf app loaded or not.

I think I will do it like ADOBE Reader. Put a application accelerator... in the autostart being a small hello world wpf app...

Comment: You should be more specific about what your application does when initializing. I could write a WPF app that is smaller and calculates factorials during initialization - that would start up even slower than yours.

Comment: @Venemo:

as I said before I just bind a hard-coded generic List of 30 entities to a DataGrid. No database access at all!

Comment: What happens if you take DataGrid out of the equation ...

Comment: One of the issues is the Font Cache service has to start up before the first WPF app starts up.

Comment: Try a hello world WPF app (simple text on otherwise empty window) and see how long it takes to start up.  If it's fast, your app is doing something slow, if it's slow the CLR and WPF libs are likely to blame.

Comment: I updated my initial post see above!

Comment: This is one reason companies like Adobe create splash screens for their applications.  It doesn't solve the problem, but it will improve the perceived performance.

Comment: well my photoshop here starts within 2 seconds ok its a native .exe...

Comment: One question no one's asked yet is, "Does it matter if it takes 10 seconds to start?" ... If, for example, your app is loaded once a week, and left open from then on - then it probably isn't. Is it really worth your time to optimise the cold-startup time, or is there something your users would appreciate your time spent on more? :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28VS.80%29.aspx) to pre-compile your assemblies. That should help.

Edit:
There may be one thing that can help. If this is a wpf application based on the "new wpf application" template in visual studio, your application will reference a bunch of assemblies that you may not use. Try to remove all unused assemblies from your applications references and see if that helps.

Comment: It might, although I believe that some or all of the JIT code gets cached on the first execution.

Comment: It should, but the question is on how to make the cold start (ie. first time the app is run) faster. As long as the app doesn't do much at start up, I don't think there is anything other than ngen that will help.

Comment: Ngen on a small app makes the cold start slower.  Bigger DLL to load.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx) by Jossef Goldberg.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not normal, do you make connections to a database or to some network? Waiting for some OS resource?

Answer (score 1):

.Net apps start slowly compared to natively compiled apps, but that sounds excessive.  [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) may offer some insight into what it is waiting for.